# CV draft file problems

Tags: cv, adjustwidth

I have downloaded a CV draft file for LaTeX and I've got some problems and need your help. The draft files consist of two files, one of which is the class file (twentysecondcv.cls) and the other one is the main file (template.tex) posted below. My problems are:

1-In the first page, there is a blue column at the left side of the page. I need that column (just the color, not the text) to be on other pages too.

2-If I enter the first part of each sub-environment long, it will cause in disharmony with other parts and sends some text out of paper (see picture below) [image]

3-Although every environment is arranged in an alternative colors of gray and blue (see below), the last parts are all gray. Is there a way to make them also alternative? The codes are pasted below. Thanks

Titles are fine:

[image: Titles with alternative gray and blue colors]

Titles get all gray in the end:

[image: Last titles are all gray]

***Template.tex***

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Twenty Seconds Resume/CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.1 (8/1/17)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Carmine Spagnuolo (cspagnuolo@unisa.it) with major modifications by
% Vel (vel@LaTeXTemplates.com)
%
% License:
% The MIT License (see included LICENSE file)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[letterpaper]{twentysecondcv} % a4paper for A4
\hyphenation{consumptive Hydraulic Reasoning Meybod Development supervision relations}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    PERSONAL INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% If you don't need one or more of the below, just remove the content leaving the command, e.g. \cvnumberphone{}

\profilepic{alice.jpeg} % Profile picture

\cvname{Majid Zare} % Your name
\cvjobtitle{M.Sc Student at Amirkabir University of Technology
\newline(Tehran Polytechnic)} % Job title/career

\cvdate{31 October 1992} % Date of birth
\cvaddress{University of Tehran (Kooy) Dormitory,
Kargar St, Tehran, Tehran, Iran} % Short address/location, use \newline if more than 1 line is required
\cvnumberphone{+98 9333599070} % Phone number
\cvsite{http://linkedin.com/in/mjdzr/} % Personal website
\cvmail{majid.zare@aut.ac.ir} % Email address

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    ABOUT ME
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\aboutme{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SKILLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Skill bar section, each skill must have a value between 0 an 6 (float)
\skills{{Written Communication/5.9},{Verbal Communication/5.6},{Teamwork/5.3},{Flexibility/5.1},{Computing Skills/5.6},{Analysing and Investigating/5.6}}

%------------------------------------------------

% Skill text section, each skill must have a value between 0 an 6
\skillstext{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeprofile % Print the sidebar



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions

\twentyitem{2015-present}{M.Sc. in {\normalfont Water Resources Management}}{GPA:17.24/20 (To date)}{\emph{Amirkabir University of Technology (Tehran Polytechnic)}}
    \twentyitem{2011-2015}{B.Sc. in Civil and Environmental Engineering}{GPA:13.85/20}{\emph{Amirkabir University of Technology (Tehran Polytechnic)}}
    \twentyitem{2007-2011}{Highschool Diploma}{GPA:19.11/20}{\emph{Shahid Sadoughi Highschool (NODET)}}
    %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Thesis Status
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Thesis Status}

\begin{twentyshort} % Environment for a short list with no descriptions
    \twentyitem{Thesis Title}{Coordinated operation and dam removal
effects on meeting consumptive and
environmental demands of natural
ecosystems \newline(Case study: Urmia Lake basin)}{To Be Defended}{\emph{Supervisor: Dr.S.Jamshid Mousavi}}\\
    \twentyitem{Seminar Title}{An International Review of Dam Removal Experiments, Incentives and Consequences}{Score:20/20}{\emph{Supervisor: Dr.Reza Maknoon}}\\
    %\twentyitemshort{<dates>}{<title/description>}
\end{twentyshort}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    PUBLICATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Publications}

\begin{twentyshort} % Environment for a short list with no descriptions
    \twentyitem{2017}{M.Zare; M.Ahmadi; Multi-decadal Variability of Parameters Influence on Hydrological Fluxes under Climate.
Change}{(Submitted)}{\emph{Journal of Hydrology}}
    \twentyitem{2017-present}{S.Ghanbari; M.Zare; M.Ahmadi; Combining Hydrologic and Hydraulic Parameters in Suspended Sediment Estimation (preliminary title).\hspace{45pt}}{(In Progress)}{\emph{(Journal Paper)}}
    %\twentyitemshort{<dates>}{<title/description>}
\end{twentyshort}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Teaching Assistantship
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Teaching Assistantship}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
\twentyitem{2017-present}{Technical English}{}{\emph{Lecturer: Dr.Saeed Torkzaban}}
\twentyitem{2016-present}{Advanced Groundwater}{}{\emph{Lecturer: Dr.Saeed Torkzaban}}
\twentyitem{2016-2017}{Technical English}{}{\emph{Lecturer: Dr.Mehdi Ahmadi}}
    %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Research Assistantship
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Research Assistantship}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
\twentyitem{2017-present}{Simulation of economical scenarios for Urmia Lake restoration (under supervision of Urmia Lake Restoration National Committee, Sharif University of Technology)}{}{\emph{Supervisor: Dr.Hossein Pourzahedi}}
\twentyitem{2015-present}{Standardization of Showerheads
based on hydraulic and convenience
specifications}{}{\emph{Supervisor: Dr.Babak Khorsandi}}
    %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Language Scores
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Language Scores}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
\twentyitem{TOEFL}{Reading: 27; Listening: 25; Speaking: 20; Writing: 30}{9/9/2017}{\emph{Total: 102}}
\twentyitem{GRE}{Verbal Reasoning: TBA; Quantitative Reasoning: TBA; \newline Analytical Writing: TBA;}{11/2/2017}{\emph{(To Be Taken)}}
    %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\\\\\\\\\\
\end{twenty}
%%NEW PAGE

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Selected Courses
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Selected Courses}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
\twentyitem{B.Sc.}{Water \& Wastewater Engineering \& Project}{15.75/20}{\emph{Instructor: Dr.Sara Nazif}}
\twentyitem{}{Engineering Hydrology + Project}{16/20}{\emph{Instructor: Dr.S.Jamshid Mousavi}}
\twentyitem{}{Numerical Analysis}{17.75/20}{\emph{Instructor: Dr.Kourosh Shahverdiani}}
\twentyitem{}{Technical English}{16.5/20}{\emph{Instructor: Dr.Taghi Ebadi}}
\twentyitem{}{English for the Students of Engineering}{17/20}{\emph{Instructor: Dr.Mohammad Reza Eslami Khouzani}}
\twentyitem{M.Sc.}{Operation Research}{17.4/20}{\emph{Instructor: Dr.Amir Golroo}}
\twentyitem{}{Hydrological Models}{17.5/20}{\emph{Instructor: Dr.Mehdi Ahmadi}}
\twentyitem{}{RS \& GIS Application in Civil Engineering \& Lab}{19.7/20}{\emph{Instructor: Dr.Mehdi Ahmadi}}
\twentyitem{}{Water Quality Control}{18.5/20}{\emph{Instructor: Dr.Mehdi Ahmadi}}
\twentyitem{}{Advanced Engineering Hydrology}{15.75/20}{\emph{Instructor: Dr.S.Jamshid Mousavi}}
\twentyitem{}{Water Resources \& Management Systems Analysis (I)}{16.5/20}{\emph{Instructor: Dr.S.Jamshid Mousavi}}
\twentyitem{}{Advanced Groundwater}{16.2/20}{\emph{Instructor: Dr.Hamed Ketabchi}}

    %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Course Projects
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Course Projects}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
\twentyitem{B.Sc.}{Water \& Wastewater Engineering \& Project: Real-time simulation of sewer design, storm design and water distribution systems in Meybod city (Yazd, Iran) }{}{\emph{Utilities: EPANET, SewerCAD, StormCAD}}
\twentyitem{}{Engineering Hydrology: Simulation and manual calibration of Gilan Basin using semi-distributed models}{}{\emph{Model: HEC-HMS}}
\twentyitem{}{Road Engineering Project}{}{\emph{Utilities: AutoCAD, Autodesk Land}}
\twentyitem{}{Steel Structures Project}{}{\emph{Utilities: AutoCAD, ETABS2015, SAFE2015}}
\twentyitem{}{Concrete Structures Project}{}{\emph{Utilities: AutoCAD, ETABS2015}}
\twentyitem{}{Estimation \& Cost \& Project (Case Study: Energy Engineering and Physics Department, Amirkabir University of Technology )}{}{\emph{Utility: Microsoft Excel}}
\twentyitem{M.Sc.}{Operation Research project: Minimizing the payback period of dam construction project using branch-and-bound algorithm (Case Study: Cheragh Veys Dam, Urmia Basin)}{}{\emph{Utilities: LINGO, MATLAB}}
\twentyitem{}{Hydrological Models project: Multi-decadal Variability of Parameters Influence on Hydrological Fluxes under Climate (Case Study: Eagle Creek Watershed)}{}{\emph{Utilities: MATLAB, SWAT}}
\twentyitem{}{RS \& GIS Application in Civil Engineering \& Lab project: Contingency phase mapping for disaster management (earthquake) (Case Study: Tehran Metropolis)}{}{\emph{Utility: ArcGIS}}
\end{twenty}
\\\\\\
%%NEW PAGE
\begin{twenty}
\twentyitem{}{Water Quality Control project: Multi-objective minimization of river oxygen loss and the cost of industrial waste release using genetic algorithm}{}{\emph{Utilities: MATLAB, Microsoft Excel}}
\twentyitem{}{Advanced Hydrology: Simulation and automatic calibration of Gilan Basin using semi-distributed models}{}{\emph{Model: HEC-HMS}}
\twentyitem{}{Advanced Groundwater: Project}{}{\emph{Utilities: SUTRA, MODFLOW}}

    %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Computer Skills
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Computer Skills}

\begin{twenty}
\twentyitem{Water Resources Management}{HEC-HMS, EPANET, Stormcad, SWAT, ArcSWAT, SWAT-CUP, LINGO, SewerCAD, Weka, Arc-GIS, SUTRA, MODFLOW, MODSIM, QUAL2E, QUAL2K}{}{}
\twentyitem{Civil}{Autodesk Land, ETABS, SAP2000, SAFE, AutoCAD, Aimsun, Expert Choice}{}{}
\twentyitem{General}{LaTeX, Microsoft Word, Microsoft Excel, Microsoft Powerpoint}{}{}
\twentyitem{Programming}{MATLAB, Python, Fortran}{}{} %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Certifications
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Certifications}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a short list with no descriptions
    \twentyitem{2017}{Internetional Certification for EAP
(Enlish for Academic Purposes)
Workshop}{}{\emph{K.N.Toosi University; 32
hours}}
\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    AWARDS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Honors and Awards}

\begin{twentyshort} % Environment for a short list with no descriptions
    \twentyitemshort{2015}{Ranked 454th in the Nationwide Civil Engineering M.Sc Examination
(among more than 25,000 contestants).}\\
    \twentyitemshort{2011}{Ranked 366th in the Nationwide Mathematics and Physics University
Entrance Examination (among more than 350,000 contestants).}\\
    \twentyitemshort{2007}{Admitted to the NODET High school (National Organization for
Development of Exceptional Talents).}
    %\twentyitemshort{<dates>}{<title/description>}
\end{twentyshort}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    WORK EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Work Experiences}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
    \twentyitem{2015}{Mellat Bank Construction Company (Chitgar Project)}{3 months}{\emph{Civil Engineering Training course}}
\twentyitem{2017-present}{Institute of Transportation Studies \& Research (ITSR) under supervision of Urmia Lake Restoration National Committee (ULRNC)}{}{\emph{Researcher and project consultant}}
\twentyitem{2014-present}{Self-employed}{}{\emph{Over 30 translation projects (General, academic and expert English)}}
\end{twenty}    %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
%\end{twenty}

\section{Interests}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
    \twentyitem{Research}{Agricultural Studies, Climate Change, Groundwater Modelling, Runoff Simulations, Water Quality Modelling, Programming, Field Research, Laboratory Research, Teamwork}{}{}
\twentyitem{Other}{Photography, Writing research articles/stoties/critiques, Public relations}{}{}
\end{twenty}    

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    OTHER INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SECOND PAGE EXAMPLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\newpage % Start a new page

%\makeprofile % Print the sidebar

%\section{Other information}

%\subsection{Review}

%Alice approaches Wonderland as an anthropologist, but maintains a strong sense of noblesse oblige that comes with her class status. She has confidence in her social position, education, and the Victorian virtue of good manners. Alice has a feeling of entitlement, particularly when comparing herself to Mabel, whom she declares has a ``poky little house," and no toys. Additionally, she flaunts her limited information base with anyone who will listen and becomes increasingly obsessed with the importance of good manners as she deals with the rude creatures of Wonderland. Alice maintains a superior attitude and behaves with solicitous indulgence toward those she believes are less privileged.

%\section{Other information}

%\subsection{Review}

%Alice approaches Wonderland as an anthropologist, but maintains a strong sense of noblesse oblige that comes with her class status. She has confidence in her social position, education, and the Victorian virtue of good manners. Alice has a feeling of entitlement, particularly when comparing herself to Mabel, whom she declares has a ``poky little house," and no toys. Additionally, she flaunts her limited information base with anyone who will listen and becomes increasingly obsessed with the importance of good manners as she deals with the rude creatures of Wonderland. Alice maintains a superior attitude and behaves with solicitous indulgence toward those she believes are less privileged.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

***twentysecondcv.cls***

```
\ProvidesClass{twentysecondcv}[2017/01/08 CV class]
\LoadClass{article}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    REQUIRED PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{ifmtarg}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{pgffor}
\RequirePackage{marvosym}
\RequirePackage{parskip}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    COLOURS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{sidecolor}{HTML}{E7E7E7}
\definecolor{mainblue}{HTML}{0E5484}
\definecolor{maingray}{HTML}{B9B9B9}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    MISC CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\color{gray}} % Make \textbf produce coloured text instead

\pagestyle{empty} % Disable headers and footers

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % Disable paragraph indentation

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SIDEBAR DEFINITIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm} % Left margin
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm} % Top margin

\newlength\imagewidth
\newlength\imagescale
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagewidth}{5cm}
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagescale}{\imagewidth/600}

\newlength{\TotalSectionLength} % Define a new length to hold the remaining line width after the section title is printed
\newlength{\SectionTitleLength} % Define a new length to hold the width of the section title
\newcommand{\profilesection}[1]{%
    \setlength\TotalSectionLength{\linewidth}% Set the total line width
    \settowidth{\SectionTitleLength}{\huge #1 }% Calculate the width of the section title
    \addtolength\TotalSectionLength{-\SectionTitleLength}% Subtract the section title width from the total width
    \addtolength\TotalSectionLength{-2.22221pt}% Modifier to remove overfull box warning
    \vspace{8pt}% Whitespace before the section title
    {\color{black!80} \huge #1 \rule[0.15\baselineskip]{\TotalSectionLength}{1pt}}% Print the title and auto-width rule
}

% Define custom commands for CV info
\newcommand{\cvdate}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvdate}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvmail}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvmail}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvnumberphone}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvnumberphone}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvaddress}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvaddress}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvsite}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvsite}{#1}}
\newcommand{\aboutme}[1]{\renewcommand{\aboutme}{#1}}
\newcommand{\profilepic}[1]{\renewcommand{\profilepic}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvname}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvname}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvjobtitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvjobtitle}{#1}}

% Command for printing the contact information icons
\newcommand*\icon[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt, fill=mainblue,mainblue,text=white] (char) {#1};}}

% Command for printing skill progress bars
\newcommand\skills[1]{
    \renewcommand{\skills}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{
                \draw[fill=maingray,maingray] (0,\i) rectangle (6,\i+0.4);
                \draw[fill=white,mainblue](0,\i) rectangle (\y,\i+0.4);
                \node [above right] at (0,\i+0.4) {\x};
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

% Command for printing skills text
\newcommand\skillstext[1]{
    \renewcommand{\skillstext}{
        \begin{flushleft}
            \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{
                \x$ \star $\y
            }
        \end{flushleft}
    }
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SIDEBAR LAYOUT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\makeprofile}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [rectangle, fill=sidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    %------------------------------------------------

    \begin{textblock}{6}(0.5, 0.2)

        %------------------------------------------------

        \ifthenelse{\equal{\profilepic}{}}{}{
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\imagescale,y=-\imagescale]
                    \clip (600/2, 567/2) circle (567/2);
                    \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{\profilepic}};
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{center}
        }

        %------------------------------------------------

        {\Huge\color{mainblue}\cvname}

        %------------------------------------------------

        {\Large\color{black!80}\cvjobtitle}

        %------------------------------------------------

        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm} @{\hskip 0.5cm}p{5cm}}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvdate}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Info}} & \cvdate\\}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvaddress}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Letter}} & \cvaddress\\}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvnumberphone}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Telefon}} & \cvnumberphone\\}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvsite}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Mundus}} & \cvsite\\}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvmail}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{@}} & \href{mailto:\cvmail}{\cvmail}}
        \end{tabular}

        %------------------------------------------------

        \ifthenelse{\equal{\aboutme}{}}{}{
            \profilesection{About me}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \aboutme
            \end{flushleft}
        }

        %------------------------------------------------

        \profilesection{Skills}

        \skills
        \skillstext


        %------------------------------------------------

    \end{textblock}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    COLOURED SECTION TITLE BOX
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Command to create the rounded boxes around the first three letters of section titles
\newcommand*\round[2]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[anchor=north west, draw,rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=1.6pt, minimum size=5.5mm, text height=3.6mm, fill=#2,#2,text=white](char){#1};%
}

\newcounter{colorCounter}
\newcommand{\sectioncolor}[1]{%
    {%
        \round{#1}{
            \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
            maingray\or%
            mainblue\or%
            maingray\or%
            mainblue\or%
            maingray\or%
            mainblue\or%
            maingray\or%
            mainblue\or%
            maingray\or%
            mainblue\else%
            maingray\fi%
        }%
    }%
    \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    {%
        \color{gray}%
        \Large\sectioncolor{#1}%
    }
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
    \par\vspace{.5\parskip}{%
        \large\color{gray} #1%
    }
    \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    LONG LIST ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

% New environment for the long list
\newenvironment{twenty}{%
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
}

\newcommand{\twentyitem}[4]{%
    #1&\parbox[t]{0.815\textwidth}{%
        \textbf{#2}%
        \hfill%
        {\footnotesize#3}\\%
        #4\vspace{\parsep}%
    }\\
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SMALL LIST ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

% New environment for the small list
\newenvironment{twentyshort}{%
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
}

\newcommand{\twentyitemshort}[2]{%
    #1&\parbox[t]{0.815\textwidth}{%
        \textbf{#2}%
    }\\
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    MARGINS AND LINKS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[left=7.6cm,top=0.1cm,right=1cm,bottom=0.2cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}

\RequirePackage{hyperref}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The left bar is added with a call to `\makeprofile`. Within that macro, `tikz` places it in the background. I extracted that component and added it as part of the shipout routine for each page:

   ```
   \usepackage{atbegshi}
   \AtBeginShipout{
     \ifnum\value{page}=4
       \AtBeginShipoutDiscard
     \else
       \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
         \node [rectangle, fill=sidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
       \end{tikzpicture}
     \fi
   }
   ```

   There was an addition of another page with the above usage, so I discarded page 4 (knowing your output only comprised 3 pages.
2. You can set very lengthy "headers" in a `[t]`op-aligned `tabular` and manually set the appropriate line-breaks:

   ```
   \begin{twenty}
     \twentyitem{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} Water \\ Resources \\ Management\end{tabular}}
       {HEC-HMS, EPANET, Stormcad, SWAT, ArcSWAT, SWAT-CUP, LINGO, SewerCAD, Weka, Arc-GIS, SUTRA, MODFLOW, MODSIM, QUAL2E, QUAL2K}{}{}
     \twentyitem{Civil}
       {Autodesk Land, ETABS, SAP2000, SAFE, AutoCAD, Aimsun, Expert Choice}{}{}
     \twentyitem{General}
       {\LaTeX, Microsoft Word, Microsoft Excel, Microsoft Powerpoint}{}{}
     \twentyitem{Programming}
       {MATLAB, Python, Fortran}{}{}
     %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
   \end{twenty}
   ```
3. The current class specifies the colour of sections as a case, and therefore has to specify each individually:

   ```
   \newcommand{\sectioncolor}[1]{%
       {%
           \round{#1}{
               \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
               maingray\or% 0
               mainblue\or% 1
               maingray\or% 2
               mainblue\or% 3
               maingray\or% 4
               mainblue\or% 5
               maingray\or% 6
               mainblue\or% 7
               maingray\or% 8
               mainblue\else% 9
               maingray\fi% 10...
           }%
       }%
       \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
   }
   ```

   Note that after the eleventh section, all `\section`s are coloured using `maingray`. Since you have an alternating colouring requirement, just switch the colour using `\ifodd`:

   ```
   \renewcommand{\sectioncolor}[1]{%
     {%
       \round{#1}{
         \ifodd\value{colorCounter}%
         mainblue\else%
         maingray\fi%
       }%
     }%
     \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
   }
   ```

---

Here is your entire CV with some other minor layout tweaks:

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Twenty Seconds Resume/CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.1 (8/1/17)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Carmine Spagnuolo (cspagnuolo@unisa.it) with major modifications by
% Vel (vel@LaTeXTemplates.com)
%
% License:
% The MIT License (see included LICENSE file)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[letterpaper]{twentysecondcv} % a4paper for A4
\hyphenation{consumptive Hydraulic Reasoning Meybod Development supervision relations}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipout{
  \ifnum\value{page}=4
    \AtBeginShipoutDiscard
  \else
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node [rectangle, fill=sidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \fi
}
\renewcommand{\sectioncolor}[1]{%
  {%
    \round{#1}{
      \ifodd\value{colorCounter}%
      mainblue\else%
      maingray\fi%
    }%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    PERSONAL INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% If you don't need one or more of the below, just remove the content leaving the command, e.g. \cvnumberphone{}

\profilepic{picture} % Profile picture

\cvname{Majid Zare} % Your name
\cvjobtitle{M.Sc Student at Amirkabir University of Technology
  \newline(Tehran Polytechnic)} % Job title/career

\cvdate{31 October 1992} % Date of birth
\cvaddress{University of Tehran (Kooy) Dormitory,
  Kargar St, Tehran, Tehran, Iran} % Short address/location, use \newline if more than 1 line is required
\cvnumberphone{+98 9333599070} % Phone number
\cvsite{http://linkedin.com/in/mjdzr/} % Personal website
\cvmail{majid.zare@aut.ac.ir} % Email address

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    ABOUT ME
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\aboutme{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SKILLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Skill bar section, each skill must have a value between 0 an 6 (float)
\skills{%
  {Written Communication/5.9},%
  {Verbal Communication/5.6},%
  {Teamwork/5.3},%
  {Flexibility/5.1},%
  {Computing Skills/5.6},%
  {Analysing and Investigating/5.6}}

%------------------------------------------------

% Skill text section, each skill must have a value between 0 an 6
\skillstext{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeprofile % Print the sidebar


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
  \twentyitem{2015-present}
    {M.Sc.~in {\normalfont Water Resources Management}}
    {GPA:17.24/20 (To date)}
    {\emph{Amirkabir University of Technology (Tehran Polytechnic)}}
  \twentyitem{2011-2015}
    {B.Sc.~in Civil and Environmental Engineering}
    {GPA:13.85/20}
    {\emph{Amirkabir University of Technology (Tehran Polytechnic)}}
  \twentyitem{2007-2011}
    {Highschool Diploma}
    {GPA:19.11/20}
    {\emph{Shahid Sadoughi Highschool (NODET)}}
  %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Thesis Status
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Thesis Status}

\begin{twentyshort} % Environment for a short list with no descriptions
  \twentyitem{Thesis Title}
    {Coordinated operation and dam removal effects on meeting consumptive and environmental demands of natural
      ecosystems \newline(Case study: Urmia Lake basin)}
    {To Be Defended}
    {\emph{Supervisor: Dr.~S.~Jamshid Mousavi}}
  \twentyitem{Seminar Title}
    {An International Review of Dam Removal Experiments, Incentives and Consequences}
    {Score:20/20}
    {\emph{Supervisor: Dr.~Reza Maknoon}}\\
  %\twentyitemshort{<dates>}{<title/description>}
\end{twentyshort}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    PUBLICATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Publications}

\begin{twentyshort} % Environment for a short list with no descriptions
  \twentyitem{2017}
    {M.~Zare; M.~Ahmadi; Multi-decadal Variability of Parameters Influence on Hydrological Fluxes under Climate Change}
    {(Submitted)}
    {\emph{Journal of Hydrology}}
  \twentyitem{2017-present}
    {S.~Ghanbari; M.~Zare; M.~Ahmadi; Combining Hydrologic and Hydraulic Parameters in Suspended Sediment Estimation (preliminary title).}
    {(In Progress)}
    {\emph{(Journal Paper)}}
  %\twentyitemshort{<dates>}{<title/description>}
\end{twentyshort}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Teaching Assistantship
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Teaching Assistantship}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
  \twentyitem{2017-present}
    {Technical English}
    {}
    {\emph{Lecturer: Dr.~Saeed Torkzaban}}
  \twentyitem{2016-present}
    {Advanced Groundwater}
    {}
    {\emph{Lecturer: Dr.~Saeed Torkzaban}}
  \twentyitem{2016-2017}
    {Technical English}
    {}
    {\emph{Lecturer: Dr.~Mehdi Ahmadi}}
  %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Research Assistantship
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Research Assistantship}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
  \twentyitem{2017-present}
    {Simulation of economical scenarios for Urmia Lake restoration (under supervision of Urmia Lake 
      Restoration National Committee, Sharif University of Technology)}
    {}
    {\emph{Supervisor: Dr.~Hossein Pourzahedi}}
  \twentyitem{2015-present}
    {Standardization of Showerheads based on hydraulic and convenience specifications}
    {}
    {\emph{Supervisor: Dr.~Babak Khorsandi}}
  %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Language Scores
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Language Scores}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
  \twentyitem{TOEFL}
    {Reading: 27; Listening: 25; Speaking: 20; Writing: 30}
    {9/9/2017}
    {\emph{Total: 102}}
  \twentyitem{GRE}
    {Verbal Reasoning: TBA; Quantitative Reasoning: TBA; \newline Analytical Writing: TBA;}
    {11/2/2017}
    {\emph{(To Be Taken)}}
  %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}

\clearpage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Selected Courses
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Selected Courses}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
  \twentyitem{B.Sc.}
    {Water \& Wastewater Engineering \& Project}
    {15.75/20}
    {\emph{Instructor: Dr.~Sara Nazif}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {Engineering Hydrology + Project}
    {16/20}
    {\emph{Instructor: Dr.~S.~Jamshid Mousavi}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {Numerical Analysis}
    {17.75/20}
    {\emph{Instructor: Dr.~Kourosh Shahverdiani}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {Technical English}
    {16.5/20}
    {\emph{Instructor: Dr.~Taghi Ebadi}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {English for the Students of Engineering}
    {17/20}
    {\emph{Instructor: Dr.~Mohammad Reza Eslami Khouzani}}
  \twentyitem{M.Sc.}
    {Operation Research}
    {17.4/20}
    {\emph{Instructor: Dr.~Amir Golroo}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {Hydrological Models}
    {17.5/20}
    {\emph{Instructor: Dr.~Mehdi Ahmadi}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {RS \& GIS Application in Civil Engineering \& Lab}
    {19.7/20}
    {\emph{Instructor: Dr.~Mehdi Ahmadi}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {Water Quality Control}
    {18.5/20}
    {\emph{Instructor: Dr.~Mehdi Ahmadi}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {Advanced Engineering Hydrology}
    {15.75/20}
    {\emph{Instructor: Dr.~S.~Jamshid Mousavi}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {Water Resources \& Management Systems Analysis (I)}
    {16.5/20}
    {\emph{Instructor: Dr.~S.~Jamshid Mousavi}}
  \twentyitem{}{Advanced Groundwater}{16.2/20}{\emph{Instructor: Dr.~Hamed Ketabchi}}
  %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Course Projects
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Course Projects}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
  \twentyitem{B.Sc.}
    {Water \& Wastewater Engineering \& Project: Real-time simulation of sewer design, storm design and 
      water distribution systems in Meybod city (Yazd, Iran)}
    {}
    {\emph{Utilities: EPANET, SewerCAD, StormCAD}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {Engineering Hydrology: Simulation and manual calibration of Gilan Basin using semi-distributed models}
    {}
    {\emph{Model: HEC-HMS}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {Road Engineering Project}
    {}
    {\emph{Utilities: AutoCAD, Autodesk Land}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {Steel Structures Project}
    {}
    {\emph{Utilities: AutoCAD, ETABS2015, SAFE2015}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {Concrete Structures Project}
    {}
    {\emph{Utilities: AutoCAD, ETABS2015}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {Estimation \& Cost \& Project (Case Study: Energy Engineering and Physics Department, Amirkabir 
      University of Technology)}
    {}
    {\emph{Utility: Microsoft Excel}}
  \twentyitem{M.Sc.}
    {Operation Research project: Minimizing the payback period of dam construction project using 
      branch-and-bound algorithm (Case Study: Cheragh Veys Dam, Urmia Basin)}
    {}
    {\emph{Utilities: LINGO, MATLAB}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {Hydrological Models project: Multi-decadal Variability of Parameters Influence on Hydrological 
      Fluxes under Climate (Case Study: Eagle Creek Watershed)}
    {}
    {\emph{Utilities: MATLAB, SWAT}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {RS \& GIS Application in Civil Engineering \& Lab project: Contingency phase mapping for 
      disaster management (earthquake) (Case Study: Tehran Metropolis)}
    {}
    {\emph{Utility: ArcGIS}}
\end{twenty}

\clearpage

\begin{twenty}
  \twentyitem{}
    {Water Quality Control project: Multi-objective minimization of river oxygen loss and 
      the cost of industrial waste release using genetic algorithm}
    {}
    {\emph{Utilities: MATLAB, Microsoft Excel}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {Advanced Hydrology: Simulation and automatic calibration of Gilan Basin using semi-distributed models}
    {}
    {\emph{Model: HEC-HMS}}
  \twentyitem{}
    {Advanced Groundwater: Project}
    {}
    {\emph{Utilities: SUTRA, MODFLOW}}
  %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Computer Skills
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Computer Skills}

\begin{twenty}
  \twentyitem{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} Water \\ Resources \\ Management\end{tabular}}
    {HEC-HMS, EPANET, Stormcad, SWAT, ArcSWAT, SWAT-CUP, LINGO, SewerCAD, Weka, Arc-GIS, SUTRA, MODFLOW, MODSIM, QUAL2E, QUAL2K}{}{}
  \twentyitem{Civil}
    {Autodesk Land, ETABS, SAP2000, SAFE, AutoCAD, Aimsun, Expert Choice}{}{}
  \twentyitem{General}
    {\LaTeX, Microsoft Word, Microsoft Excel, Microsoft Powerpoint}{}{}
  \twentyitem{Programming}
    {MATLAB, Python, Fortran}{}{}
  %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Certifications
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Certifications}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a short list with no descriptions
  \twentyitem{2017}
    {Internetional Certification for EAP (Enlish for Academic Purposes) Workshop}
    {}
    {\emph{K.N.Toosi University; 32 hours}}
\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    AWARDS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Honors and Awards}

\begin{twentyshort} % Environment for a short list with no descriptions
  \twentyitemshort{2015}
    {Ranked 454th in the Nationwide Civil Engineering M.Sc Examination (among more than 25,000 contestants).}
  \\
  \twentyitemshort{2011}
    {Ranked 366th in the Nationwide Mathematics and Physics University Entrance Examination (among more than 350,000 contestants).}
  \\
  \twentyitemshort{2007}
    {Admitted to the NODET High school (National Organization for Development of Exceptional Talents).}
  %\twentyitemshort{<dates>}{<title/description>}
\end{twentyshort}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    WORK EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Work Experiences}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
  \twentyitem{2015}
    {Mellat Bank Construction Company (Chitgar Project)}
    {3 months}
    {\emph{Civil Engineering Training course}}
  \twentyitem{2017-present}
    {Institute of Transportation Studies \& Research (ITSR) under supervision of Urmia Lake Restoration 
      National Committee (ULRNC)}
    {}
    {\emph{Researcher and project consultant}}
  \twentyitem{2014-present}
    {Self-employed}
    {}
    {\emph{Over 30 translation projects (General, academic and expert English)}}
  %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}

\section{Interests}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
  \twentyitem{Research}
    {Agricultural Studies, Climate Change, Groundwater Modelling, Runoff Simulations, 
      Water Quality Modelling, Programming, Field Research, Laboratory Research, Teamwork}{}{}
  \twentyitem{Other}
    {Photography, Writing research articles/stoties/critiques, Public relations}{}{}
\end{twenty}

\end{document}
```